# Populate textbox on website vb.net issue

Tags: vb.net

I do a lot of web scraping to automate some of my job functions. I'm trying to populate this text-box on this [website](https://providerportal.careimprovementplus.com/Login.aspx).

I've done this on about 10 other websites with no problems, but for some reason, this one is giving me trouble. I've searched all the entries on here from others doing this, but I don't see what I am missing.

Here is my code I am using. I'm using Visual Studio 2008, version 9.0.3. I've also tried invokemember click after setting the attribute etc. It finds the element, so I know I am getting that far, the text-box is just not populating. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

```
    theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
        If curElement.OuterHtml.Contains("ctl00$CPHContent$txtUserID") Then
            WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_CPHContent_txtUserID").SetAttribute("value", "TEST")                
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Since you know the `id` of the element you want, there's no need for getting a list by tagname and looping over them..  just `WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_CPHContent_txtUserID")` will do it.  If it exists then the login form is visible.. if not exists then the login form is unavailable.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I removed the loop and just have the single line of code setting the attribute, but it still does not populate.

Comment: Where in your code have you written this?  What event handler?

Comment: It won't let me paste my code into one comment, to many chars. But i know the page is loading, i check the ReadyState of the webbrowser1. Which i've used on 10 other sites and it works. I'll split the code up in multiple comments.

Comment: Public Sub WaitForPageLoad()
        AddHandler WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf PageWaiter)
        While Not pageready
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
        pageready = False
    End Sub

Comment: Public Sub PageWaiter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
        If WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
            pageready = True
            RemoveHandler WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf PageWaiter)
        End If
    End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I used, and it appears to work fine *most* of the time.

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    Dim userNameElement As HtmlElement = Nothing

    userNameElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_CPHContent_txtUserID")
    If Not Nothing Is userNameElement Then
        userNameElement.SetAttribute("value", "TESTing")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://providerportal.careimprovementplus.com/Login.aspx")

End Sub
```

The first couple times it wouldn't set the attribute.  But after the page was cached it worked perfect every time.  There's probably a weird timing issue.  I bet if you put a `Thread.Sleep(250)` as the first statement in the `DocumentCompleted` event it would solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah mine still doesn't work. Something so simple causing so much frustration :-\